# How to align highchart legend when using multiple pie chart in one container?

Tags: highcharts

Hi I have two pie chart in one container using HighCharts.

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        type: 'pie'
    },
    plotOptions: {
        series: {
        dataLabels: {
            enabled: false
        }
      }
    },
    series: [{
        size: '50%',
        center: ['25%', '50%'],
        data: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
        showInLegend: true,
    }, {
        size: '50%',
        center: ['75%', '50%'],
        data: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
        showInLegend: true,
    }]
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/f9dLhuv0/

[image]

Right now I want to align each pie chart legend so user can differentiate which legend belongs to which pie chart.

How to solve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now, it is not possible. There can be only one legend on the chart.

As a workaround, you can split them into separate containers:

```js
Highcharts.chart('container1', {
  chart: {
    type: 'pie'
  },
  title: {
    text: ''
  },
  plotOptions: {
    series: {
      dataLabels: {
        enabled: false
      }
    }
  },
  credits: {
    enabled: false
  },
  series: [{
    size: '80%',
    data: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
    showInLegend: true,
  }]
});

Highcharts.chart('container2', {
  chart: {
    type: 'pie'
  },
  title: {
    text: ''
  },
  plotOptions: {
    series: {
      dataLabels: {
        enabled: false
      }
    }
  },
  credits: {
    enabled: false
  },
  series: [{
    size: '80%',
    data: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
    showInLegend: true,
  }]
});
```

```css
#container1 {
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
}

#container2 {
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<div id="container1"></div>
<div id="container2"></div>
```

**Demo:**

- http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/x9pc38za/

Comment: Thanks if there is no build solution I guess this is the way to go

Comment: Yes, at least for now. There are plans to implement an advanced legend module in the future Highcharts releases and then it will be possible.